# I have installed major upgrade successfully but it also allowing another previous version install in wix

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have installed major upgrade (say #206) successfully and included code as in (#206):

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="no" OnlyDetect="yes" Language="1033" Property="NEWPRODUCTFOUND" />
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.0.0.178" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMaximum="no" Language="1033" Property="UPGRADEFOUND" />
</Upgrade>
```

Scenario is:
I have installed build #177 then upgraded to build #206. It is still allowed to install #177 which I want to prevent this downgrade.

From build #178 onward I have changed product GUID for major upgrade and which is working fine.
Please suggest how to prevent this. I don't want to downgrade build below 177. If I have done major upgrade on `build no <= 177`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the how the comparison of versions is done in MSI by default - 1.0.0.123 is treated the same as e.g. 1.0.0.33. You either have to increase your revision version to make the installer detect this as an older version or use a workaround.

You might for instance create a custom action to check against this very Revision version and place it e.g. before InstallValidate:

```
<CustomAction Id='MyVersionCheck' Return='check' (...) />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='MyVersionCheck' Before='InstallValidate' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Some more information can be found [in this article](http://akutz.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/preventing-same-version-downgrades-with-wix/), for informations about how to create custom actions i'd recommend [this blog entry](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/from-msi-to-wix-part-5-custom-actions.aspx) as a starting point.